# How to add list of elements as options in select html tag

Tags: java, wicket

I have list of string which I want to add as option in select tag in html. In wicket I found selectOption example: http://www.mkyong.com/wicket/wicket-select-example/ but there is one problem. I dont want to add options in html code. Then I found component SelectOptions which have patameter list but I didnt find any example with it. I dont know what should I add as last paramater in this component - render. Is this right component to add my list into select or I have to rewrite my list to html page ?

Comment: Are you looking for a DropDownChoice? https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/dropdownchoice-examples.html

Comment: yes it is thx a lot but I cant accept your answer because it is just comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [DropDownChoice excamples](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/dropdownchoice-examples.html) in the Wicket wiki. The DDC Component has a few constructors, so you can adopt it to your needs.